# DatePicker Bootstrap: invert day and month after selection

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I have this date picker realized with bootstrap:

[image]

Then i try to change date, although I forced the format as seen in the following section of the code as "dd/mm/yyyy", it switch automatically days with month and viceversa.

[image]

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group"  id="datainiziocpform">
                          <label for="datainizio">Data d'inizio:</label>
                          <div class="input-group date">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input id="datainizio" type="text" class="form-control" name="datainizio" value="{{$data[0]->datainizio}}" />

                          </div>


                        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $('#datainiziocpform .input-group.date').datepicker({
              startDate:$('#datainizio').val(),
              dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
              autoclose:true,
              language: "it"
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
```

try like this.

Comment: After having checked, datepickerjs works with "format" instead of "dateFormat".

Answer (score 1):

Try this `format: "dd/mm/yyyy"` instead of `dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"`

```js
 $('#datainiziocpform .input-group.date').datepicker({
  startDate:$('#datainizio').val(),
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose:true,
  language: "it"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="form-group"  id="datainiziocpform">
  <label for="datainizio">Data d'inizio:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input id="datainizio" type="text" class="form-control" name="datainizio"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you: I confirm that datepicker.js works with "format", but sukumar2267 replied before.